# How to make div and textarea positioning same

Tags: html, css

I am want to make the positioning and style same of a div and a textarea. How can I do this? Specifying same font to both of the components are easy, but the text of the textarea spawns verically and that for the div spawns horizontally. I am new in CSS. Any information is appreciable. Thank you.

Edit:

Here is what I want to achive: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/VYtwK/).  The textarea can contain atmost 140 character. But the div does not reflecting the same positioning as textarea.

Answer (score 0):

This gives a `div` the basic style of a non-styled `textarea`

`div{height:35px; width:176px; border:1px solid #999; margin-bottom:1em;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/UGepT/

To adjust the `width` of the `textarea`, you would use `cols` in the `textarea` tag

Ex. `<textarea cols="50"></textarea>`

Height of the `textarea` can be adjusted in the CSS

Here is another example, with both styled

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/UGepT/2/